# Is the BPM of Filenet P8 can be used for other thing than managing workflows of documents

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-process-engine

Can we use the BPM of Filenet for other things than managing documents?
I would use it to manage process independants of documents.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can, you can make pretty much any process you want. Using the component manager and custom component queue you can make java components to perform all kinds of tasks. For example I have built a workflow that can download files from a website, unzip them and store the files in filenet.

I think you should be able to do one of the bpm trainings @ IBM

It could help you to get an idea of all the possibilities

Comment: Thank you Robert! What about a case where we don't work with files. Must we always work with files?
What about the equivalent of human tasks with BPMN?

Comment: There is no need to work with files, and yes you can also add human interaction steps in various styles(standard processor, custom form processor, ibm forms ect) save the data to the workflow or a create custom objects. Especialy with the component manager and stepprocessors you can do anything that you want. Normally the basic examples are always document review soltions thus working with documents.